# Basic Authorization with Silverlight navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to use HtmlPage.Window.Navigate to a page that requires authorization. If I load the silverlight app in chrome this format works just fine:

https://username:password@mylocation.mydomain.com/10/10_xxxx_xxxx.pdf

However, when I try to run this same app in IE, IE throws a "Invalid Operation Exception". It seems that IE doesn't support the username:password format that Chrome/FF do (and yes, I tried the Urls directly). Is there any way to provide Silverlight basic authorization information to use when navigating to the url?